# latex question: comutative diagrams side by side

Tags: visualization

I would like to put the following two diagrams side be side:
{\Large$$
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{i}\arrow[swap]{dr}{j} & M \arrow{d}{j'}\\
& N
\end{tikzcd}
$$}
and
{\Large$$
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{j}\arrow[swap]{dr}{i} & N \arrow{d}{i'}\\
& M
\end{tikzcd}
$$}
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Wrong site! Try tex.stackexchange.com instead.